# Problema de Lógica en Bases de datos

Tags: sql, relaciones, lógica

Estoy realizando una base de datos para el control de equipos de computo, entre ellos esta la instalación de software en los equipos, tenemos un software que la licencia permite reactivación 5 veces
ejemplo: un equipo se da de **alta** y se le activa el software X, a los 6 meses el equipo se descompone y la licencia del software X se reactiva en otro equipo nuevo pero el equipo nuevo ya estaba dado de alta entonces entro en un **Mantenimiento**

Aqui tenemos dos maneras de activar dicha licencia del software por medio de alta en el sistema y por medio de un mantenimiento las tablas quedarían así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi problema esta en como ligar de manera correcta la relacion entre mantenimiento y software sin llegar a tener problemas de discrepancias o poca fidelidad en los datos resguardados

Comment: y porque no relacionar mantenimiento con equipoSoftware y la relacion equipos con equipo software se elimina, ahi tenes cerrado el circulo

Comment: CmBuffa si aplique esa forma y creo es la mejor solucion